# Python search a file for text using input from another file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and programming. I need some help with a python script. There are two files each containing email addresses (more than 5000 lines). Input file contains email addresses that I want to search in the data file(also contains email addresses). Then I want to print the output to a file or display on the console. I search for scripts and was able to modify but I'm not getting the desired results. Can you please help me?

```
dfile1 (50K lines)
yyy@aaa.com
xxx@aaa.com
zzz@aaa.com


ifile1 (10K lines)
ccc@aaa.com
vvv@aaa.com
xxx@aaa.com
zzz@aaa.com

Output file
xxx@aaa.com
zzz@aaa.com



datafile = 'C:\\Python27\\scripts\\dfile1.txt'
inputfile = 'C:\\Python27\\scripts\\ifile1.txt'

with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
names = f.readlines()

outputlist = []

with open(datafile, 'r') as fd:
  for line in fd:
    name = fd.readline()
    if name[1:-1] in names:
        outputlist.append(line)
    else:
        print "Nothing found"
 print outputlist
```

New Code

```
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
    names = f.readlines()
outputlist = []

with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name = f.readlines()
        if name in names:
            outputlist.append(line)
        else:
            print "Nothing found"
    print outputlist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
names=[]
outputList=[]
with open(inputfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        names.append(line.rstrip("\n")

myEmails=set(names)

with open(outputfile) as fd, open("emails.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in fd:
        for name in names:
            c=line.rstrip("\n")
            if name in myEmails:
                print name #for console
                output.write(name) #for writing to file
```

Comment: It might fail for a file that has no newline at the end; you could call `.rstrip("\n")` to fix it. Also a list is ineffective here, you could use `set()` as in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

mitan8 gives the problem you have, but this is what I would do instead:

```
with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
    names = set(i.strip() for i in f)

output = []

with open(datafile, "r") as f:
    for name in f:
        if name.strip() in names:
            print name
```

This avoids reading the larger datafile into memory.

If you want to write to an output file, you could do this for the second `with` statement:

```
with open(datafile, "r") as i, open(outputfile, "w") as o:
    for name in i:
        if name.strip() in names:
            o.write(name)
```

Comment: It might fail for a file that has no newline at the end for [this reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933813/python-search-a-file-for-text-using-input-from-another-file#comment29665073_19933884)

Comment: A file is an iterator over lines in Python. No need to call .readlines()

Comment: `if name in names: o.write(name)` -> `if name.strip() in names: o.writeline(name)`. And you could open several files in a single `with`-statement (just add comma).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Edited! The reason I had `readlines` was because I didn't delete it after adding the generator expression to call `strip` on the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not use a pair of sets?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

data_filename = 'dfile1.txt'
input_filename = 'ifile1.txt'

with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_file:
    input_addresses = set(email_address.rstrip() for email_address in input_file.readlines())

with open(data_filename, 'r') as data_file:
    data_addresses = set(email_address.rstrip() for email_address in data_file.readlines())

print(input_addresses.intersection(data_addresses))
```

Comment: `(... for email_address in data_file)` is enough. A file is an iterator over lines in Python. No need to call `.readlines()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove `name = fd.readline()` since you've already got the line in the for loop. It'll read *another* line in addition to the for loop, which reads one line every time. Also, I think `name[1:-1]` should be `name`, since you don't want to strip the first and last character when searching. `with` automatically closes the files opened.

*PS*: How I'd do it:

```
with open("dfile1") as dfile, open("ifile") as ifile:
    lines = "\n".join(set(dfile.read().splitlines()) & set(ifile.read().splitlines())
print(lines)
with open("ofile", "w") as ofile:
    ofile.write(lines)
```

In the above solution, basically I'm taking the union (elements part of both sets) of the lines of both the files to find the common lines.

Comment: Lovely solution, but is it appropriate to use `readlines()` if the input is ~10k lines? Honest question, I don't have much experience with that scale of memory usage.

Comment: @kevinsa5 Each line takes about 60 bytes (Python's string type has quite a bit of overhead), then the set should be about 600k+overhead (less than a megabyte in any case).

Comment: I'm not familiar with using sets, but will this get the email addresses he's looking for with the input file? Or does this get everything?

Comment: @BraydonKains My answer just finds the common lines, which is the same thing as his problem, or so I think.

Comment: `.readlines()` leaves a newline inside the string; you could use `file.read().splitlines()` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, if the file doesn't have a trailing newline then that would be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue stems from the following:

```
name = fd.readline()
if name[1:-1] in names:
```

`name[1:-1]` slices each email address so that you skip the first and last characters. While it might be good in general to skip the last character (a newline `'\n'`), when you load the name database in the "dfile"

```
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
    names = f.readlines()
```

you are including newlines. So, don't slice the names in the "ifile" at all, i.e.

```
if name in names:
```

Comment: I change it to if name in names. but it is giving me this error.       File "C:\Python27\scripts\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    name = f.readlines()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: Can you make sure the indentation in your code is correct? That will help me understand your error.

Comment: Here is my code:with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
    names = f.readlines()
#    print names

outputlist = []

with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
 for line in f:
  name = f.readlines()
  if name in names:
   outputlist.append(line)
  else:
   print "Nothing found"
 print outputlist

Comment: @HarryD Could you edit the question to have that code please?

Comment: @HarryD: You have a typo in your "New Code" that is giving you the error. It should be `name = f.readline()` (not `readlines()`).