# search a file for text using input from another file with a twist [Python]

Tags: python

I want to use a queryfile.txt as the source file, which will be used for searching and matching each line to a datafile.txt. But the datafile.txt has a different structure.

queryfile.txt should look like this:

```
Gina Cooper

Asthon Smith

Kim Lee
```

while the datafile.txt looks like this:

```
Gina Cooper

112 Blahblah St., NY

Leigh Walsh

09D blablah, Blah

Asthon Smith

another address here

Kim Lee

another address here
```

I need to get the names AND the line after it. Here's the code to get matching names in both files, which is a modified code from dstromberg (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19934477):

```
with open('querfile.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    input_addresses = set(names.rstrip() for names in input_file)

with open('datafile.txt', 'r') as data_file:
    data_addresses = set(names.rstrip() for names in data_file)

with open('names_address.txt', 'w') as output:
    names_address=("\n".join(input_addresses.intersection(data_addresses)))
    output.write(names_address)
```

In summary, what I want to see in my outfile (names_address.txt) are the names PLUS the addresses corresponding to their names, which is basically the next line. I just started playing with python a month ago and I believe I am stuck.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the options instead and then you can just grab the next index:

```
for i in range(len(data_addresses):
  for entry in input_addresses:
    if entry==data_addresses[i]:
      output.write(data_address[i] + data_address[i+1])
```

This might not have great time complexity, but your data set appears

Comment: Hi @AlbertRothman,

thanks for the suggestion. I've tried using this code this way:


`with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_file:

    input_addresses = input_file.readlines()


with open(data_filename, 'r') as data_file:

    data_addresses = data_file.readlines()


with open("emails.txt", "w") as output:

 for i in range(len(data_addresses)):

  for entry in input_addresses:

   if entry==data_addresses[i]:

    output.write(data_addresses[i] + data_addresses[i+1])`


but I've no idea why it could not iterate the last line of the input_addresses. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, that would depend on what the error is. It looks like it should work, is the output unexpected, are you getting an error? Are you sure it's not going to the end of the file? In you comment you have removed the call to strip so there might just be some extra whitespace.

Comment: I did not get any errors with the code in my previous comment. 


If I use `data_addresses = [names.rstrip() for names in data_file]` it gives me the desired output but not the desired format, which is a single line of values with no spaces. So I just altered the formatting with `output.write(data_addresses[i] + "\n" + data_addresses[i+1] + "\n")`. It doesn't look pretty but it works. 


What should I do to make this code efficient for large dataset (i.e., hundred thousand lines)?

Comment: Having just done roughly the same thing with roughly the same algorithm, but with csv's, your looking at about a minute per 1000 lines processed(obviously depending on the computer your running it on), which works out to less than two hours to run. But if you want to really speed up this process then you will probably need to  feed the data into a database and do your processing there; databases are made for processing large data sets efficiently. If you want to still use python take a look at the built in SQL library. It will probably still take about 1-2 hours to feed the data into your db.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this:

```
with open('datafile.txt', 'r') as data_file:
    data_addresses = set(names.rstrip() for names in data_file)
```

To this:

```
with open('datafile.txt', 'r') as data_file:   
    data = data_file.readlines()
    data_addresses = list(filter(None, [line for line in data if not line[0].isdigit()]))
```